# How to convert json array to backbone collection

Tags: backbone.js

This is the json data returned by a rest-full service as a response:

```
{
    "calendarEvent":[
        {
            "event_date":"2014-09-01",
            "event_location":"bbbbb",
            "event_name":"aaaa"
        },
        {
            "event_date":"2014-08-04",
            "event_location":"hotel",
            "event_name":"bday"
        },
        {
            "event_date":"2014-09-11",
            "event_location":"cccc",
            "event_name":"aaaa"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I convert this json array to backbone collection?

Answer (score 2):

Override [`collection.parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) when you want to customize how Backbone handles a server response :

> **parse** collection.parse(response, options)
>   parse is called by Backbone whenever a collection's models are returned by the server, in
>   fetch. The function is passed the raw response object, and should
>   return the array of model attributes to be added to the collection.

In your case, your collection would look like:

```
var C = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    parse: function(response) {
        return response.calendarEvent;
    }
});
```